# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can obviously not just plug and chug since I cannot divide by $0$. So how can I manipulate:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}$$
in order to evaluate it?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2+2x}{x}$?

Comment: Well, if you do not want to devide by x, which is no problem since $x\to\infty$ you could use L'Hospital. Also it is obviously divergent.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to factorize :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x(x+ 2)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}x+2=\infty$$
Or more probably :
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2 + 2x}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(x+ 2)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}x+2=2$$

Answer (score 1):

$\underset{x\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{{{x}^{2}}+2x}{x}=\infty$ because
\begin{align}
  & \forall \,N>0\,\,\exists \,M>0\,\,:\,\,x>M\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\frac{{{x}^{2}}+2x}{x}>N \\ 
 & \qquad\qquad\qquad \frac{{{x}^{2}}+2x}{x}=x+2>N \\ 
\end{align}
let
$$M>N-2$$