# How to find $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

**By factorization:**

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}\tag{1}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{-x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}$$

If I input $x=-\infty$, the limiting value seems to be $-1$. But according to [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vuptuofvot), the limiting value should be $1$.

**By L'Hopital's rule:**

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}}{-1}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{1}{\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x+1}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}}{1}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}$$

I can't get a determinate form.

**My questions:**

1. How do I find $(1)$ using factorization?
2. How do I find $(1)$ using L'Hopital's rule?

---

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1828904/768162)

Comment: What is $\sqrt{x^2}$ ?

Comment: A very simple way of finding the limit is to find the limit of its square, which is clearly $1$. Since the function is positive you can  take square root at the end.

Comment: This is one of the function expressions involving a ratio with a radical in which the "l'Hopital" method merely causes the radical to "volley back and forth" between the numerator and denominator.  The factorization method is really what is called for.  It might also be mentioned that the even-root radical causes a "splitting" of the horizontal asymptote:  the function has different limits "at positive and negative infinity".

Comment: @boojum Does L'Hopital's rule not work here?

Comment: It doesn't "work" in the sense that it doesn't resolve the limit, as you found by obtaining the same expression in your third and seventh lines.  Eventually, you "give up" and apply factorization...

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sir, I understood that the limit of the square is $1$: 

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2+2x}{x^2}=1$$

However, I didn't understand what you meant by "Since the function is positive you can take square root at the end." Could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: We are taking limit as $x \to -\infty$ and the denominator  is positive for all $x <0$. So the given function is itself positive and the answer is the positive square root of $1$ which is $+1$. [It would have been $-1$ if the function was negative].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. In other words,

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2+2x}{x^2}}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

Have I conveyed your message correctly, sir?

Comment: Yes, you surely have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct, you've just made a common mistake regarding square roots.

Writing out your manipulation of the numerator, you did $\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} = \sqrt{x^2(1 + \frac2x)} = \sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1 + \frac2x} = x\sqrt{1 + \frac2x}.$ However, recall that because the principal square root is always positive (by definition) we actually have that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|,$ and because we're looking at the limit as $x$ approaches $-\infty$ we consider negative $x,$ so $|x| = -x,$ explaining the sign discrepancy.

Comment: Understood. What about L'Hopital's rule? Does it not work here?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic As other answers/comments have indicated, L'Hopital's rule just doesn't yield a ton here because of how derivatives on radicals work, you kinda just get stuck in a loop. It still applies, the limits you got still go to $1,$ but it just doesn't help a ton here. (technically there is a little stunt you could pull to get that the limit must go to $1$ if it exists, but I really see no reason for it when it just ends up being a worse version of the argument that actually works)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}&=&\frac{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{-x}\\
&=&\frac{|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{-x}\\
&=&\frac{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{-x} \text{ since }x<0\\
&=&\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, the problem lies in the first step. It should be
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-x\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}}}{-x}$$
Notice that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $|x|$, so not always $x$. In this case, for $x\to-\infty$, it should be $-x$.

For the second question, it seems to be not recommended to use L'Hopital's rule in this example.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is based on @KaviRamaMurthy's comments.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451437/how-to-find-lim-x-to-infty-frac-sqrtx22x-x?noredirect=1#comment9322477_4451437)

**Alternative way to find the limit:**

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$$

$$\text{[$\sqrt{x^2+2x}$ is positive. Moreover, $-x$ is also positive. So, $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$ is positive.]}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{|x|}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$

$$=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x^2+2x}{x^2}}$$

$$\text{[Recall that $\lim_{x\to a} \sqrt[n]{f(x)}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}$]}$$

$$=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to-\infty} 1+\frac{2}{x}}$$

$$=\sqrt{1}$$

$$=1\text{(Ans.)}$$

Let us consider another case where the function is negative. Let us consider $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x}$.

**Another case:**

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{-x}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{|x|}$$

$$=-\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$$

$$=-\sqrt{\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x^2+2x}{x^2}}$$

$$=-\sqrt{\lim_{x\to-\infty} 1+\frac{2}{x}}$$

$$=-\sqrt{1}$$

$$=-1\text{(Ans.)}$$

Comment: This is correct.